# Browser keeps crashing becuase of a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, while-loop

Basically i'm coding a code that takes the first line from a textarea, then send it to a php code and get back the response. However this is not happening whenever i put the data the browser stops working this is the code that i'm working in

```
function getNewSocks() {
  socksList.splice(0, 1);
  $('#socks').val(socksList.join("\n"));
}
var socksList = $("#socks").val().split("\n");
while (socksList.length) {
  var getTheSocksLine = $.trim(socksList[0].replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  var getIP = $.trim(getTheSocksLine.split(":")[0]);
  var getPort = $.trim(getTheSocksLine.split(":")[1]);

  if (typeof getIP == "undefined" || typeof getPort == "undefined" || getIP == "" || getPort == "") {
    alert("typeof");
    socksDieResultDisplay(getIP + ":" + getPort);
    getNewSocks();
  }
  else if (getTheSocksLine.match(/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,6}$/) == null) {
    alert("error");
    socksDieResultDisplay(getIP + ":" + getPort);
    getNewSocks();
  }

  else {
    $.ajax({
      url: "system/checkerPostHandler.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: "checkSocks=CheckSocksNowPlease&ip=" + getIP + "&port=" + getPort,
      success: function (getResponse) {
        alert("PHP Response=>" + getResponse + " jQuery Response=>" + getIP);
        if (socksList.length != 0) {
          getNewSocks();
        }

      }
    });
  }

}
```

i swear to god that now it has been 3-4 hours trying to find out what is the problem! help me please

Comment: Here's your problem: `while (socksList.length) {` - infinite loop as soon as there's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a counter and copmapre it with the `socksList.length` if the counter is `<=` to the `socksList.length` then the loop will run otherwise will exit.

The issue with your code is the loop condition will always true and it will always run. The `socksList.length` condition will always true if the `socksList.length` is not `0`.

**Example.**

```
function getNewSocks() {
  socksList.splice(0, 1);
  $('#socks').val(socksList.join("\n"));
}
var socksList = $("#socks").val().split("\n");
let counter = 0;
while (counter <= socksList.length) {
  var getTheSocksLine = $.trim(socksList[counter].replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  var getIP = $.trim(getTheSocksLine.split(":")[0]);
  var getPort = $.trim(getTheSocksLine.split(":")[1]);

  if (typeof getIP == "undefined" || typeof getPort == "undefined" || getIP == "" || getPort == "") {
    alert("typeof");
    socksDieResultDisplay(getIP + ":" + getPort);
    getNewSocks();
  }
  else if (getTheSocksLine.match(/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,6}$/) == null) {
    alert("error");
    socksDieResultDisplay(getIP + ":" + getPort);
    getNewSocks();
  }

  else {
    $.ajax({
      url: "system/checkerPostHandler.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: "checkSocks=CheckSocksNowPlease&ip=" + getIP + "&port=" + getPort,
      success: function (getResponse) {
        alert("PHP Response=>" + getResponse + " jQuery Response=>" + getIP);
        if (socksList.length != 0) {
          getNewSocks();
        }

      }
    });
  }
  counter++;
}
```

You could use `socksList.forEach` or `for of` as well.

**`for of` example:**

```
for (const socks of socksList) {
  var getTheSocksLine = $.trim(socksList[socks].replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  //..other code
}
```

**`forEach` example:**

```
socksList.forEach( socks => {
  var getTheSocksLine = $.trim(socksList[socks].replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  //..other code
});
```